# How do I setup a rule to match on HTTP host when using Firebase hosting rewrites?

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have a Firebase project in which I have configured static hosting. I have two domains `test1.domain.com` and `test2.domain.com`, both configured within the control panel. Each has an A record pointing to the given server IP addresses shown during configuration.

Without any configuration, browsing both domains individually serves up the `index.html` of the `public` directory.

```
.
├── .firebaserc
├── firebase.json
└── public
    ├── 404.html
    ├── index.html
    ├── test1.domain.com
    │   └── index.html
    └── test2.domain.com
        └── index.html
```

Below is example pseudocode for what I'm tying to achieve, effectively splitting the single hosting space into two. In words, any URI resource at `test1.domain.com` will serve the corresponding content within that sub-directory. Same applies to `test2.domain.com`

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "https://test1.domain.com/**",
    "destination": "/test1.domain.com/**"
  },
  {
    "source": "https://test2.domain.com/**",
    "destination": "/test2.domain.com/**"
  }
]
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Such virtual domain hosting is currently not possible on Firebase Hosting. All domains on a single Firebase Hosting project will serve the same content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase hosting with multiple directories at multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581735/firebase-hosting-with-multiple-directories-at-multiple-domains)